# c++ library for conversion to any local time (defined by linux zoneinfo string)

Tags: c++, timezone

I am looking for a C++ library to convert UTC time to any local time and vice versa. Not only to the timezone of the computer, but to any given timezone. The timezone is defined by unix zoneinfo string (eg. "Europe/Paris") - the Olson string. The library should be available both on windows and on linux.

Is there such a thing?

Answer (score 3):

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/date_time/local_time.html

Comment: The answer is *always* boost.